# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined inputmask.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error:

> **Paused on exception
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

On this line:

```
factory(window.dependencyLib || jQuery);
```

I tried to update the files with a new version but i get a lot of bugs.

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("inputmask", ["inputmask.dependencyLib"], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
        module.exports = factory(require("./inputmask.dependencyLib"));
    } else {
        factory(window.dependencyLib || jQuery);
    }
}
```

Infinite loop page loading..
I developed an application after this tutorial where i integrated in the index platform.

Screenshot error:

[image: Screenshot error]

Tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-poll-with-phpixie/

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery on the page? In the [tutorial example](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-poll-with-phpixie/) it places the jQuery script include between the `<head>` tags:

```
<head>
  <title>PHPixie polls</title>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: i added on the index.php where the poll application it's integrated.
Now:
!1!==CKEDITOR.fire("inline",f)&&CKEDITOR.inline(a,f.config))};CKEDITOR.domReady(function(){!CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline&&CKEDITOR.inlineAll()})}(),CKEDITOR.replaceClass="ckeditor",function(){function a(a,e,m,l){if(!CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible)return null;a=CKEDITOR.dom.element.get(a);if(a.getEditor())throw'The editor instance "'+a.getEditor().name+'" is already attached to the provided element.';var d=new CKEDITOR.editor(e,a,l);l==CKEDITOR.ELEMENT_MODE_REPLACE&&(a.setStyle("visibility","hidden"),d._.required=

Comment: Please can you post with something more descriptive.